# What happens with the protagonists in Rogue One? (major spoilers)

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

It appears that by the end of Rogue One

> that every single one of the protagonists have died: Jyn, Bodhi, Cassian, Andor, Galen, K2, etc.
>  Are there any major characters introduced in the film on the rebel side who survived?

For the purpose of the question, this excludes people who appear in ANH.

Comment: No. They all dead.

Comment: They are one with the force; the force is with them.

Comment: Imagine the sheer number of questions emerging where they were through Episode I-VI if they survived... Nope, easier that way.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bOjc70f4p8

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - unfortunately, Jar Jar wasn't terminated at the end of III - thus leading to speculation that he's a Sith Lord.  My point: there are still two movies and many "StarWars Stories" left for loose ends.

Comment: Not only easier that way, but more realistic. It was pretty clear that the trip would be a one-way ticket.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### They died

All the protagonists died, whether in battle, at the hands of the Death Star, or otherwise.

- Jyn and Cassian:

  > The rumbling overwhelmed all other sound. Jyn tightened her grip on
  >   Cassian, and he found the strength to hold her. The world grew
  >   brighter, emerald at first and then a clean, purifying white. In Jyn’s
  >   mind, the cave below the broken hatch was illuminated with the
  >   strength of a sun, and then the walls turned to dust and there was no
  >   longer a cave but only her spirit and heart and everything she had
  >   ever been: the daughter of Galen and Lyra and Saw, the angry fighter
  >   and the shattered prisoner and the champion and the friend.
  >
  > Soon all those things, too, burned away, and Jyn Erso—finally at
  >   peace—became one with the Force.
  >
  > <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>
- Bodhi:

  > Bodhi Rook heard the ring of metal once, twice, in the cabin, and then
  >   the soft clatter of something rolling across the deck. He turned in
  >   time to glimpse the detonator. He heard nothing as the cabin flared
  >   impossibly bright.
  >
  > Like a pilot should, he died with his ship.
  >
  > <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>
- K-2:

  > With approximately three seconds until total shutdown, K-2SO listened
  >   to Cassian’s voice cry his name one last time. Then, without regret,
  >   the droid turned his weapon on the console. The comm cut out. With the
  >   controls now reduced to a melted plastoid-metal compound, the
  >   stormtroopers would have considerable difficulty entering the vault.
  >
  > With one second left until total shutdown, K-2SO chose to mentally
  >   simulate an impossible scenario in which Cassian Andor escaped alive.
  >
  > The simulation pleased him.
  >
  > <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>
- Chirrut:

  > The words of the chant echoed in Chirrut Îmwe’s heart once more before
  >   he died: I am one with the Force and the Force is with me.
  >
  > <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>
- Baze:

  > When death had come for him in the shadow of the walker, he had faced
  >   it with defiance. Now there was grief.
  >
  > There was no fear.
  >
  > Baze Malbus died in pain, but it did not last long.
  >
  > <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

**And so forth.**

Answer (score 3):

Sure, depending on who you count. **General Draven** and **Admiral Raddus** were both created for the film and survived (at least as far as I can recall). General Syndulla (Hera Syndulla from SW: Rebels) was mentioned on film, which may be counted by some as an "introduction" and seemingly her ship, the *Ghost*, survived (presumably therefore with her on it).

Comment: Admiral Raddus probably did not survive; his flagship was disabled and boarded by Vader.

Comment: True, but we don't see him die, so ya never know...

Comment: And the Ghost was trapped in orbit of Scarif and was likely destroyed also, explaining Luke being the only Jedi left.

Comment: @Valorum Ehhh, I doubt it. I really can't imagine Dave Filoni choosing to end Rebels that way, with all the characters dying in a scene we've already seen where all the characters die. He's a bit more creative than that.

Comment: @TVAnn - It actually ties up the Kanan/Ezra story very nicely. You can have Ahsoka be there as well.

Comment: the thing about rebels and rogue1... you know the ending because of ANH. none present in ANH pretty much ensures they die otherwise some nasty loose ends to tie up (or a major relaunch of the original starwars...).

Comment: @Naib Not really, I don't remember Mon Mothma being in ANH. Or Admiral Ackbar. Just like how if the intercom hadn't happened to announce "General Syndulla" or if the *Ghost* didn't happen to be in Scarif, we wouldn't know the Rebels characters were there. Sometimes things just are happening in the background.

Comment: You do not need to take my statement literally... "that fly wasn't seen in ANH" you know what I mean. Those who went to Scarif were on a suicide mission. THose on the planet were dead and that sealed not only from ANH story but anyone seeing it developing. The space battle a bit vaguer

Comment: @Naib Sorry, my point is that just because a character is not seen later does not mean they are not present in-universe somewhere. Also, just because many people die does not mean everyone dies. It could be that the *Ghost*'s crew dies on Scarif. Or it could not. I am simply asserting that based on the info we have, such a fate is *unknown* at present, and until further information presents itself, that's the best we can say.

Comment: Also one thing to point out though is....that most of the time it comes down to the comment "no jedi" exist in ANH.....Ashoka saw herself no longer as jedi and that could also be true for the other two (it is NEVER mentioned if there are any other force users in the rebellion....in other cells than the one at yavin for example or not. only no other jedi).