# Is Jyn Force-Sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

After watching the film I never really got the impression that Jyn was force-sensitive. She seems very skilled and perhaps at least a bit lucky but never really too much.

However when reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148143/58193) I saw the following quote (emphasis mine):

> The rumbling overwhelmed all other sound. Jyn tightened her grip on
> Cassian, and he found the strength to hold her. The world grew
> brighter, emerald at first and then a clean, purifying white. In Jyn’s
> mind, the cave below the broken hatch was illuminated with the
> strength of a sun, and then the walls turned to dust and there was no
> longer a cave but only her spirit and heart and everything she had
> ever been: the daughter of Galen and Lyra and Saw, the angry fighter
> and the shattered prisoner and the champion and the friend.
>
> Soon all those things, too, burned away, and Jyn Erso—finally at
> peace—**became one with the Force**.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

That seems to me that she became a force ghost, although it could be me reading into it a bit much.

So is she force sensitive?

Comment: Nope. She's just a plain ordinary unimportant human who just happens to be a smoking hot ninja badass.

Comment: Becoming one with the force does not mean becoming a force ghost. Remember that the force flows through everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Probably not

Throughout the film (and novelization), Jyn never demonstrates any Force powers. She doesn’t seem to be using any overt powers, such as mind tricks or  telekinesis, but she also doesn’t exhibit the more mundane abilities common to Force-sensitives, such as uncanny aiming skills or piloting ability. Sure, she can take out a few stormtroopers, but that’s in line with what we’ve seen from other *Star Wars* characters highly trained in combat, such as Han Solo or Jango Fett.

This is generally consistent with the general vision for the film. As [mentioned](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-rogue-one-jedi-rebels/) by a *Rogue One* screenwriter:

> For a long time in the story, there were Jedi around, even if only in
> the background. Jyn’s mother was a Jedi. But **we thought that it would
> be more interesting to have a story without Force powers**, without
> lightsabers. We could explore a period of broken faith, a galaxy
> without hope.

(Of course, given that Chirrut is [probably Force-sensitive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147903/51379), they may not actually have done this….)

As for "becoming one with the Force," that’s something that anyone can do. It’s retaining one’s consciousness and ability to interact with the world to some extent (as a Force ghost) that takes skill and training.

That said, we can’t rule out the possibility that she has some (low) level of Force-sensitivity. Force sensitivity is not all or nothing: talents with the Force range from imperceptible to over 20,000. Further, her mother Lyra claimed to be able to feel the Force.

> She had lost the weight she’d gained with Jyn, but was getting soft
> after all the months of waiting around for the situation to change. In
> the months before she and Galen had departed for Vallt, she would
> often sky-cab to the Jedi Temple grounds and exercise there, basking
> in the energy of that elegant site, surrounded by a nexus of the
> Force.
>
> <sub>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel*</sub>

While this might be mere religious belief, there could be something more to it. And if Lyra is Force-sensitive, it’s possible that Jyn is as well. Nonetheless, since heritability of the Force is unreliable, we shouldn’t place too much confidence in this.

Comment: The visual guide says that her mother isn't force sensitive. She's just interested/drawn to the religion of the Jedi.

Comment: @Valorum - And the Databank says Chirrut doesn’t have Force powers. ;)

Comment: He doesn't,  but he does trust in the living Force. Evidentify that's sufficient.

Comment: @Valorum - If he doesn’t have Force powers, he has powers that come from the Force. Potayto, potahto.

Comment: Well, he seems to be an *instrument* of the Force rather than a Force-user. He has zero *control* over it, but is aware of what it's telling him.

Comment: The best answer to the Chirrut issue that I've heard is the possibility that *all* individuals in the SW universe possess some amount of Force sensitivity (penetrates and binds all life, etc.), and Chirrut simply honed and trained his (albeit small) potential into something useful. Whereas Jedi have a much greater Force sensitivity that gives them superhuman abilities even without training, and the ability to perform downright "magical" feats with sufficient training (telekinesis, mind-control, etc.).